# how to correctly authorise website logins when client uses multiple IP addresses

Tags: authentication, ip-address

I have a custom website login system built in 2015 that works very well, it appears as far as I can tell to give a high level of security and authenticity between websites, the client logs in to a login website and their details are saved to a session and then the client is transfered to a destination website, where they carry out their actions.

The security takes several key values and authenticates them on every page load to detect inconsistencies, this includes:

- hash containing amongst other things their browser key (if given)
- hash of the clients nonce generated once for each succeessful login.
- IP address
- date of login and last action taken
- Database recording and tracking of all of the above details.

This works on the basis that if a client is logged in and changes any of the above values somehow, that the authentication process would detect the inconsitency and then drop the authentication.

This works fine as it is, **BUT** I have an issue; two clients are on different systems (one is on a proxy, one is a load balancer) which seem to be swapping around their current IP address *mid-session*.

I know IP addresses can and do swap and change but I considered for a fairly small user base (~250) this would be an edge case. I did/do not expect IP addresses to change mid-session (ie once they've logged into the authentication website but before logging into their destination website, or while on the destination website).

I had not considered such things as Proxy connections and Load Balancers.

The IP address detection used is `PHP` based and is this:

```
public static function IpAddr()
    {
        if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
            $exploded_IP = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            $ipAddress = array_pop($exploded_IP);
        } elseif (array_key_exists('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER)) {
            $exploded_IP = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
            $ipAddress = array_pop($exploded_IP);
        } elseif (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED', $_SERVER)) {
            $exploded_IP = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']);
            $ipAddress = array_pop($exploded_IP);
        } elseif (array_key_exists('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
            $exploded_IP = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            $ipAddress = array_pop($exploded_IP);
        } else {
            $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        unset($exploded_IP);
        return $ipAddress;
    }
```

## Questions

- What is the best way of dealing with these sort of inconsistencies in a secure manner?

  - Should I still bother recording and using IP addresses as checkable values?
- Is there any reliable way for the server to "detect" if a user seems to be "floating about" on multiple IP addresses, yet can still be judged to be the authenticated user?

Comment: You really should be using bearer tokens.

Comment: @KenL I hadn't read up about Bearer tokens, but from an initial read through I think that the Bearer token is a similar concept to the hashed nonce I use in my login site, but I was wary of putting all my eggs in one basket, so was cross validating available data (such as IP address) with the token too.